# jQuery validate - error message wraps over in IE6

Tags: jquery

I am using jQuery validate plug in. I have configured validate plug in
for two text fields. Error message are displayed right below the text
box in case of empty or invalid input in FF and IE7.

Only IE6, displays the error message next to the text box and it wraps
it from there.

Any ideas how to fix this problem in IE6.

Answer (score 1):

Try setting the position of the error message in your CSS to absolute. (without any css or html in your question, I can't be sure).

```
label.error{
    position: absolute;
}
```

I think that validate plug in inserts labels as its error messages. If not, change your CSS accordingly.

If this results in weird positioning, you may have to wrap your form elements in a div and set its position to relative.